# How to access a redux store value? The value appear in props

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm trying to create an auth system from scratch using redux. Everything is working fine, in the redux part. The only problem is that I can't check the value `isSignedIn` in my store.
My Reducer:

```
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'SIGN_IN':
      return {...state, isSignedIn: action.payload, userId: action.payload};
```

My Action:

```
export const signIn = ({ email, password }: {email: string, password: string,}) => async (dispatch: any) => {
  try {
    const response = await AlleSys.post('/users/login', {email, password});
    dispatch({type : 'SIGN_IN', payload: response.data});
```

My component:

```
class Login extends React.Component<LoginProps> {
    state = {
        email: '',
        password: '',
        isSignedIn: ''
    };
    onEmailChange = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({email: event.target.value})
    };
    onPasswordChange = (event: any) => {
        this.setState({password: event.target.value})
    };
    submitActions = (email: string, password: string) => {
        this.props.signIn({email, password})
    };
    render() {
        return(
            <div>
                <h4>Email</h4>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.onEmailChange}/>
                <h4>Password</h4>
                <input type="text" onChange={this.onPasswordChange} />
                <button type="submit" onClick={() => this.submitActions(this.state.email, this.state.password)}>Submit</button>
            </div>
        );
    };
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: any) => {
    return {
        isSignedIn: state.auth.isSignedIn
    };
};

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    { signIn }
)(Login);
```

When I try to log using console.log(this.props) the property isSignedIn is there, but I can't figure out how to extract the value. Perhaps there is something wrong in my mapStateToProps?

Comment: it's accessible via props... `this.props.isSignedIn`

Comment: I've managed to solve. I changed the component to a functional one. ```const Login = (state) => {}``` then I use state.auth to access the prop. Probably my inital state={} was conflicting.